# maven's command about the arguments

Tags: maven, command

Does the "mvn -s setting.xml" equal "mvn -s=setting.xml"?

i.e. Can Every argument starting with "-" use blank space replace the "=" ,or the vice versa?

Thank you!!!

Comment: Just tried the "-s", and it seems OK.But I wanna know if any case is ok.

Comment: You can check the source to see how the arguments are parsed, but the docs don't seem to say anything about using =, so I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Also, any specific reason to use this style?

Comment: Some issue happens in our legacy application.It's a little bit complicated to explain, and the key is that I can replace the blank space with the "=" to ensure the maven command to be executed smoothly.Anyway, It's just a hot fix issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven uses the [Apache Commons CLI](http://commons.apache.org/cli/) library to parse command line arguments:

> Commons CLI supports different types of options:
>
> - POSIX like options (ie. tar -zxvf foo.tar.gz)
> - GNU like long options (ie. du --human-readable --max-depth=1)
> - Java like properties (ie. java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true Foo)
> - Short options with value attached (ie. gcc -O2 foo.c)
> - long options with single hyphen (ie. ant -projecthelp)

So the following are all equivolent:

1. mvn -s setting.xml ..
2. mvn --setting setting.xml ..
3. mvn --setting=setting.xml ..

Comment: Thank u for your narrowing it down to make this issue clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Using "=" for options on the command line is generally not common or best practice, so for posterity's sake it's probably not wise to use it.

You can dive deeper [in the source to confirm](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/maven/cli/MavenCli.java.html), if your curiosity is still itching.